# Configure Angular with .NET core Api request port

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, .net-6.0, angular13

I'm upgrading an older app to .NET 6 and Angular 13. I've created a new Angular + Net project from VS2022 then I've used it in upgrade. Now my app starts but seems that Angular sends api requests to a wrong port (44449 instead of 7148).

Where I can configure it? I found port configurations in:

`project.cs`:

```
<SpaProxyServerUrl>https://localhost:7148</SpaProxyServerUrl>
```

`Properties\launchSettings.json`:

```
"iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:33062",
      "sslPort": 44349
    }
```

`ClientApp\launchSettings.json`:

```
"start:windows": "ng serve --port 44449 --ssl --ssl-cert %APPDATA%\\ASP.NET\\https\\%npm_package_name%.pem --ssl-key %APPDATA%\\ASP.NET\\https\\%npm_package_name%.key",
"start:default": "ng serve --port 44449 --ssl --ssl-cert $HOME/.aspnet/https/${npm_package_name}.pem --ssl-key $HOME/.aspnet/https/${npm_package_name}.key",
```

Answer (score 1):

You have two options :

1- update the `launchSettings.json` to your desire port based on your request for HTTP or HTTPS

2- update the Angular to send request to current server port

I suggest the first one, it's easier and less error-prone the second option

If you need more help, just leave a comment!

Comment: still got:  Status Code: 404 Not Found ,Request URL: https://localhost:44449/api/login Request Method: POST Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin,  older working app makes the same request: to SPA default port

Comment: That's the problem `strict-origin-when-cross-origin` config your CORS 
take a look at this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-6.0

Comment: I've installed swagger,it can be accessed on port 7148, not on 44449 on which Angular makes the request, which is strange to me that if I make a new project, the api responds via Postman on the same port on which Angular starts, which does not happen in my project

Comment: seems the problem was proxy.conf.js configuration

Answer (score 1):

To have the Angular app call the port you want, change your ClientApp launch settings to:

```
"start:windows": "ng serve --port 7148 --ssl --ssl-cert %APPDATA%\\ASP.NET\\https\\%npm_package_name%.pem --ssl-key %APPDATA%\\ASP.NET\\https\\%npm_package_name%.key",
"start:default": "ng serve --port 7148 --ssl --ssl-cert $HOME/.aspnet/https/${npm_package_name}.pem --ssl-key $HOME/.aspnet/https/${npm_package_name}.key",
```